# Excel Formula that uses certain criteria then subtract from value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out a way to write a formula where it looks for a certain catid in column C (in this case "DD") and then subtract retone (Column D) from each retone for the other catid's. See examples below:

[image: Before]
This is before the formula

[image: After]
This is what I'd like to end up with

The other issue is I need to make sure that I'm keeping it within the same pack number (so I only want results for the catid as long as the packnumbers are the same within those catid's).

I'm also not opposed to writing this in VBA but I run into the same issue, I'm just not sure how to write the logic so it recognizes the catid under "DD" and RetOne to subtract from the other catid's and only report on pack's that are the same number. ("DD" will not always be at the top of the grouping it could be anywhere in the grouping)

Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!
-Deke

Comment: Can there ever be more than one `DD` with each `Pack`?

Comment: No. there will only ever be one DD within each pack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `DD` is only used once per PackNumber then use SUMIFS

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,A2,C:C,"DD") - D2
```

[image]

---

Or using the Dynamic Array formula `FILTER()` if one has that:

```
=@FILTER(D:D,(A:A=A2)*(C:C="DD"))-D2
```

[image]